# Working with yarn multiple workspaces in electron app

Tags: reactjs, electron, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Can I use yarn multiple workspaces with electron ?
I have a folder containe two separate projects one is a react project and the other is electron project , I want to be able to run both projects using only one npm start command (I want the electron desktop app to open and the react app to lunch) I was thinking of using yarn multiple workspaces and have a root package.json file that have a start script that start both projects . is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible using packacge.json scripts. I currently have something similar set up only that my electron and react project are still in the same workspace.
I think I will splitt them now that you gave me the idea.

Scripts could look roughly like this using cross-env, wait-on and concurrently:

```
"start-react": "cd react-folder && cross-env BROWSER=none react-scripts start"
"start-electron": "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron electron-folder"
"start-both": "concurrently \"yarn start-react\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && yarn start-electron\""
```